# Getting info on a Kind inference bug in GHC

Tags: haskell

Edward Kmett [reported](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/9200) a bug in kind inference which is pretty annoying for his category library some time ago.

I can't tell if this has been solved or not in some later version of GHC. It seems to be present in 8.10.7 and 9.0.2.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
class D a => C (f :: k) a
class C () a => D a
```

```hs
data W f (a :: k) where
  MkW :: W Maybe Int -> W f a
```

How to get information on this (like : will it be solved or not) ?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered on SO. It's hard to know when in the future GHC devs will fix this bug (if at all). I'd guess that not even the devs can answer such a question -- the bug report is 7 years old, after all. Probably the devs are prioritizing other changes. You might try to ask them directly (do they still have a mailing list?).

Comment: good to know your perspective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not answer the question that was asked ("when will the bug be fixed?"), but I think it might be useful to know that adding explicit kind signatures makes this compile with GHC 8.10.5 and GHC >= 9 (provided some extensions are enabled).

```
-- extensions for GHC 8.10.5
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, ExplicitForAll,
    PolyKinds, UndecidableSuperClasses, 
    StandaloneKindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses,
    FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Kind

type D :: Type -> Constraint
type C :: forall k. k -> Type -> Constraint

class D a => C (f :: k) a
class C () a => D (a :: *)
```

Comment: Oh this is great ! thank you ! I guess it makes my question obsolete.